# Doxygen generating 'man' but without the SYNOPSIS field

Tags: bash, shell, doxygen, manpage

I've customized my Doxygen to parse Bash scripts (.sh). I output `man` files.

The only problem is, I don't know how to add a `SYNOPSIS`. That line is always present in a Linux man and I'd like to utilize that but I don't know how.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Doxygen has the possibility to write out the word synopsis when generating a man page. When generating man pages from C code I see the SYNOPSIS tag in the man page. I think the customization for the bash scripts is lacking some parts. See also the Internet for some "conversion tools", search for doxygen bash, probably not a lot about man pages though. When you customized doxygen also have a look at the code in mangen.cpp to see what is converted. I think the method as given by @sifferman is just a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `SYNOPSIS` command by editing the Doxyfile, and modifying the `ALIASES =` tag to read

```
ALIASES = "synopsis=@par SYNOPSIS\n"
```

With this, you can put the command `@synopsis` (or `\synopsis`) in the documentation, which will result in a user-defined paragraph with the heading

> **SYNOPSIS**

As pointed out in the [doxygen documentation for the ALIAS tag](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases), you can put `\n`'s in the value part of an alias to insert newlines.

Comment: Note due to changes in the ALIASES tag you have to use `^^` instead of the `\n`